# Wireshark installed but not working on Amazon linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wireshark, yum, amazon-linux

I have installed the wireshark on amazon linux through the following command:

```
sudo yum install wireshark
```

The following commands gives me this output:

```
Package wireshark-1.8.10-25.22.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

But when i try to run wireshark command it gives the following error:

```
bash: wireshark: command not found
```

Am i missing something. Please note that i have access as root user. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wireshark command does not work. I resolved the issue by using the command below:

```
tshark -i eth0 -f "udp port 8080" -w captureFile.pcap
```

The following command captures the packets on eth0(interface name) with the filter on udp port number 8080 and then saves it to the file captureFile.pcap